# Instantiating an IEnumerable array in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering why you can do this in C#:

`IEnumerable<int>[] nums = new IEnumerable<int>[10];`

but cannot do this:

`IEnumerable<int> nums = new IEnumerable<int>();`

What is C# doing under the hood with the first statement? I thought you couldn't create instances of interfaces with the new keyword.

Comment: Where do you thin you create an instance? You allocate an array of type IEnumerable<int> in the first statement. Not a single instance is created.

Comment: "What is C# doing under the hood with the first statement?" It's creating an array of 10 IEnumerables. Not what you are looking for. Try ... num = new int[10].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first statement is creating a new array of size 10 of which item type is `IEnumerable<int>`. The array itself is a concrete type that you can create.

To set an item in this array, you would do something like this:

```
num[0] = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
```

Although the item type is `IEnumerable<int>`, you cannot create an instance of `IEnumerable<int>`. You would have to create an instance of a class that implements `IEnumerable<int>` like `List<int>`.

In the second example, you try to create an instance of `IEnumerable<int>` which is an interface, i.e. not class, and so it would not compile.

The variable type can still be `IEnumerable<int>`, but you would have to create an instance of a class that implements `IEnumerable<int>` like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> nums = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
```

Comment: Ah, this is what cleared it up for me. Before I was thinking at every index there was an integer, where in reality at every index there is something, (a List,  ArrayList, etc.) that implements IEnumerable. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You are correct in that you can't create instances of interfaces in C#. The difference between the two statements is that in the first statement you are creating an **array** of `IEnumerable<int>`, which is allowed.

The second statement would work if you create an instance of a class that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, such as `List<T>`.

An example of doing this is: `IEnumerable<int> numbers = new List<int> {1,2,3};`;

You could also do: `IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3}`

Comment: So how is this different than an `int[]` array? What is the `IEnumerable<int>` part actually doing? I thought you could only use interfaces as types to "hold" objects that implement `IEnumerable`. For instance, I could "hold" a `List<int>` in `IEnumerable<int>` if I'm only concerned with iterating over it. Is `IEnumerable<int>` just the same as an int[] array, minus being able to access elements at a particular index?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is the base interface for collections and arrays implement it. That's why you can do `IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3};`

If you only want to iterate over a collection, I would recommend that you use `IEnumerable<T>`. This allows calling code to use several different implementations of `IEnumerable<T>`.


For more information about `IEnumerable<T>`, please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I understand that that part. I guess my actual point of confusion was I was thinking integers were at every index, whereas there's something that implements an IEnumerable at every index, as Yacoub Massad pointed out. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @GabeMeister: Yes, that is correct. No problem, I'm just glad to help!